# Three.js: Add different images to each side of cylinder

Tags: three.js

I am trying to add different image to each face of a cylinder in three.js, basically I want the top, bottom and side to be different images.

This is code where I have added one image which wraps the complete cylinder.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.9,1,0.5,32,1, false);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff, side:THREE.DoubleSide, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('cake-texture-nice-golden-ginger-33420104.jpg')});
var cone = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cone);

var width = window.innerWidth; var height = window.innerHeight; var screenW = window.innerWidth; var screenH = window.innerHeight; /*SCREEN*/ var spdx = 0, spdy = 0; mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, mouseDown = false; /*MOUSE*/ document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) { mouseDown = true }, false); document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) { mouseDown = false }, false); function animate() { spdy = (screenH / 2 - mouseY) / 40; spdx = (screenW / 2 - mouseX) / 40; if (mouseDown){ cone.rotation.x = spdy; cone.rotation.y = spdx; } requestAnimationFrame( animate ); render(); } // create a point light var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFF8F ); // set its position pointLight.position.x = 10; pointLight.position.y = 50; pointLight.position.z = 130; // add to the scene scene.add(pointLight); camera.position.z = 5; var render = function () { requestAnimationFrame(render); //cone.rotation.x += 0.01; //cone.rotation.y += 0.001; //cone.rotation.z -= 0.02; window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) { var mouseX = ( e.clientX - width / 2 ); var mouseY = ( e.clientY - height / 2 ); cone.rotation.x = mouseY * 0.005; cone.rotation.y = mouseX * 0.005; cone.rotation.y += mouseY; //console.log(mouseY); }, false); renderer.render(scene, camera); }; render();
```

This is the pen for the cylinder: http://codepen.io/dilipmerani/pen/XmWNdV

---

Update-25Sep

```
var materialTop = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff, side:THREE.DoubleSide, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('chocolate_brown_painted_textured_wall_tileable.jpg')});
var materialSide = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff, side:THREE.DoubleSide, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('cake-texture-nice-golden-ginger-33420104.jpg')});
var materialBottom = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff, side:THREE.DoubleSide, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('cake-texture-nice-golden-ginger-33420104.jpg')});
var materialsArray = [];
materialsArray.push(materialTop); //materialindex = 0
materialsArray.push(materialSide); // materialindex = 1
materialsArray.push(materialBottom); // materialindex = 2
var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialsArray);
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.9,1,0.5,3,1, false);
var aFaces = geometry.faces.length;
console.log(aFaces);
for(var i=0;i<aFaces;i++) {
geometry.faces[i].materialindex;
}
var cone = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(cone);
```

Thanks

Comment: Check [MeshFaceMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshFaceMaterial). You will need to change materialindex for each group of faces (top, side, bottom) in geometry.faces[].materialindex

Comment: I am quite new to three js so I am not sure how can I use MeshFaceMaterial and geometry.faces[].materialindex, if you have a reference or a fiddle where this is done, can you please send it to me.

Answer (score 2):

Create MeshFaceMaterial:

```
var materialTop = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(...);
var materialSide = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(...);
var materialBottom = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(...);
var materialsArray = [];
materialsArray.push(materialTop); //materialindex = 0
materialsArray.push(materialSide); // materialindex = 1
materialsArray.push(materialBottom); // materialindex = 2
var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialsArray);
```

Update geometry:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.9,1,0.5,32,1, false);
faces you can get from geometry.faces
Loop faces and change materialindex: geometry.faces[faceIndex].materialindex
Print geometry.faces to console and check what it has.

var aFaces = geometry.faces.length;
for(var i=0;i<aFaces;i++) {
  if(i < 64){
    geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = 0;
  }else if(i > 63 && i < 96){
    geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = 1;
  }else{
    geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = 2;
  }
}
```

Build your cone

```
var cone = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

[Example of your updated code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOqdQB?editors=101)

Comment: I have updated the code in my question, I did not understood this "materialindex: geometry.faces[faceIndex].materialindex" can you help me out here.

Comment: Updated code and added a link with your updated code

Answer (score 0):

You should create faces in mesh's geometry with some materialindex. So you'll have 3 surfaces. And than use MeshFaceMaterial(array of material for each surface).

Comment: As I said, I am quite new to three js so I am not sure how can I use MeshFaceMaterial and geometry.faces[].materialindex, if you have a reference or a fiddle where this is done, can you please send it to me.